# Use Pumping Lemma to show that $L_7$ is not context-free

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I was studying an old test and struggled to answer this question:

Let $L_7$ be the language $\{ w@y \mid y \text{ is a substring of } w\}$, where $w, y \in \{c,d\}^*$. Use the Pumping Lemma for context-free languages to show that $L_7$ is not context-free.

Comment: What is w@y mean? Is that concatenation?

Comment: Yes @TheoBendit

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with this question; the language looks regular to me. In fact, if $y$ is allowed to be empty, then the language is simply $\{c, d\}^*$, as any such string $w$ could be written as $w\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is a substring of $w$. Even if you restrict $|y| \ge 1$, then the language is regular, since the only strings it doesn't include are $c^* d$ and $d^* c$. Does the $7$ in L7 play a part at all?

Comment: @theo: i think `@` is a symbol. Otherwise, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @rici That's a good point. And now I can see how my first comment is ambiguous.

Comment: @TheoBendit I believe you are correct that it is a symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $L7$ satisfies the Pumping Lemma and let $p$ satisfy the conditions of the Pumping Lemma as stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Formal_statement). Let
$$s = c^pd^p @ c^pd^p \in L7$$
Note that $|s| > p$. Let $u, v, w, x, y \in \{c, d, @\}^*$ satisfy the conditions of the theorem (again, as stated on Wikipedia). First, let's consider the $@$. It obviously cannot lie in $v$ or $x$, as precisely one $@$ is allowed. It cannot lie in $u$, since considering $n > 1$ will make $uv^nwx^ny$ into the form $a@b$ where $|a| < |b|$. For the same reason, this time considering $n = 0$, we cannot have $@$ be in $y$. So, the $@$ must lie in $w$.

Since $|vwx| \le p$, it follows that $v = d^m$ and $x = c^l$ for some natural numbers $m$ and $l$. Then, it follows that
$$uv^2wx^2y = c^pd^{p+m}@c^{p+l}d^p \notin L7,$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: $x$ can be empty (only $v$ and $x$ cannot be empty at the same time) and consequently $l=0$. Then $uv^2wx^2y = c^pd^{p+m}@c^{p+l}d^p = c^pd^{p+m}@c^p d^p \in L7$. But in that case $v$ must be non-empty and the case of $n=0$ leads to a word not in $L_7$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to first intersect $L_7$ with the regular language
$$ddd\cdot\{cc,cd,dc\}^+ddd@ddd\cdot\{cc,cd,dc\}^+ddd.$$
This takes away all strings where the substring is not the entire string (and some more). The result is 
$$\{ddd\cdot w\cdot ddd@ddd\cdot w\cdot ddd: w\in \{cc,cd,dc\}^+\}$$
which is very close to the copy language over three letters. Therefore you can apply the pumping lemma in the same way.

I have read "substring" as "factor," but this should even work if "substring" means "scattered substring."

Comment: If somebody downvotes this answer, because they find something wrong with it, I think they should state what they do not like. Then I can improve or delete my answer.